# How do i space my menu from my text

Tags: css

How do i have a space between my menu header and my body of text?
Also is this good practice?

```
div.body
{
    width: 6.5in;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
}

.menu ul{
    margin:0px auto;
    }
.menu li{
    width: 25%;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    }
.menu a{
    display:block;
    }
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="body">
lots of textlots of textlots of textlots of textlots of textlots of textlots of textlots of text
<the above repeated many times>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: em's are probably better than inches, but no biggie.

Comment: I would advise against using a tag name as a class or id, just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: he means don't use 'body' as a class because it's also an element name, which could consfuse readers of the CSS

Answer (score 1):

Set top margin on your body of text:

```
div.body
{
  width: 6.5in;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: fyi, this solution centers the body

Comment: and of course you can use padding, or a margin-bottom on the menu depending on your needs

Comment: ..or an invisible/blended-with-background border, useful under some circumstances where spacing would mess things up.